# scala : case class & copy() returning Any

Tags: scala, copy, slick, case-class

could you help me concerning a basic question?
I have a list of "Rdv" (meetings) where Rdv is a case class having 3 fields storing phone numbers as Strings: telBureau, telPortable & TelPrivé.

I get this list from slick, via a native SQL query; this query fills the 3 phone number fields with either a String or "null"(a null object, not the "null" string).
I would like to remove these null fields, so I wrote this:

```
var l2:List[Rdv] = liste.list()
l2=l2.map( (w:Rdv) =>{
    if ( w.telPrivé==null ) w.copy( telPrivé = "" )
})
```

but I get this error:

```
found:List[Any], required:List[Rdv]
```

so after the map I added ".asInstanceOf[List[Rdv]]" but then I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to metier.Objets$Rdv
```

It seems to ba a basic question, but I can't do that.

olivier.

Comment: If without else has type `Unit`.

Comment: @RandallSchulz to clarify, the else is taken as Unit value, so the whole expr LUBs to AnyVal or Any, unless the expr is if (k) ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try doing something like this?

```
val l2: List[Rdv] = liste list ()
val l3 = ls map{
  case x @ Rdv(_, null, _) => x.copy(telPrive = "")
  case x => x
}
```

Honestly, should should make that field, if it's nullable to be an `Option` and then have a member function which you call defined such that:

```
case class Rdv(a: String, b: Option[String], c: String){
  def realC = b getOrElse ""
}
```

Comment: hello wheaties, the answer with the "case" works. the "if then else" post was also very interesting. I could not avoid the "null" object as it is created by slick and its native sql queries. I know it is best to use option in scala, avoiding thus the null references. anyway, thanks!

Comment: If the DB column is nullable, then you should indicate that in your Slick table definition. Then you can map that column to an `Option[Whatever]` and Slick will turn `null` into `None` and non-null into `Some(value)`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var l2: List[Rdv] = liste.list()

l2 = l2 map ((w: Rdv => if (w.telPrivé == null) w.copy( telPrivé = "" ) else w)
```

Comment: This is the answer! How could I miss the missing `else`? Well done sir.

Comment: Keen eyes.  And there's a lot to be said for braces and parens style here.